# QWizardPage запустить с другого окна

Tags: qt

У меня есть программа - главное окно, как мне запустить QWizardPage, нажимая кнопку из меню главного окна. Создавая экземпляр класса и применяя метод show выдает кратковременный запуск. Даже в логах ничего нет.

Comment: Использовать `QWizardPage` без `QWizard` не имеет смысла. Что есть "кратковременный запуск"? Приведите минимальный пример кода, демонстрирующий Вашу попытку использовать мастер.

Answer (score 1):

Создаем класс `NewProjectMainPage`, унаследованный от `QWizardPage` (для примера), добавив функциональные возможности класса `QWizardPage`:

код файла NewProjectMainPage.h

```
#ifndef NEWPROJECTMAINPAGE_H
#define NEWPROJECTMAINPAGE_H

#include <QWizardPage>

namespace Ui {
class NewProjectMainPage;
}

class NewProjectMainPage : public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NewProjectMainPage(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~NewProjectMainPage();

    void initializePage() override;

    bool validatePage() override;

private:
    Ui::NewProjectMainPage *ui;
};

#endif // NEWPROJECTMAINPAGE_H
```

код файла NewProjectMainPage.cpp

```
#include "NewProjectMainPage.h"
#include "ui_NewProjectMainPage.h"

#include <QDir>

NewProjectMainPage::NewProjectMainPage(QWidget *parent) :
    QWizardPage(parent),
    ui(new Ui::NewProjectMainPage)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

NewProjectMainPage::~NewProjectMainPage()
{
    delete ui;
}

void NewProjectMainPage::initializePage()
{
    registerField("projectName*", ui->projectNameEdit);
    registerField("projectLocation*", ui->projectLocationEdit);

    setField("projectName", "Untitled");
    setField("projectLocation", QDir::homePath());

}

bool NewProjectMainPage::validatePage()
{
    if (field("projectName").toString().contains('?')) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Теперь класс можно использовать как нормальную страницу для QWizard:

```
NewProjectWizard *wizard = new NewProjectWizard(parentWidget);
wizard->setOption(QWizard::IndependentPages);
wizard->setOption(QWizard::NoBackButtonOnStartPage);

wizard->addPage(new NewProjectMainPage(wizard));
...
```

---

**Теперь собственно как показать страницу как отдельное окно, а не страницу.**

В слоте главного окна на нажатие кнопки:

```
NewProjectMainPage *page = new NewProjectMainPage(this);
page->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
page->show();
```

Вариант:

```
NewProjectMainPage *page = new NewProjectMainPage();
page->show();
```

В первым случает вы делаете окно дочерним для главного окна, для его нормального отображения потребовалось установить флаг `Qt::Window`

Во втором случает создаем окно страницы без родителя, в этом случае нормально срабатывает флаг, установленный по умолчанию: `Qt::Widget`

(не забудьте позаботиться об удалениии динамически выделенной памяти под page)

Если есть еще вопросы, пожалуйста, спрашивайте в комментарии

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, ответ использованием `QWizardPage` совместно с `QWizard`, поскольку иначе первый становится обычным виджетом, не неся полезной нагрузки от собственной специализации.

Comment: @alexis031182 ок добавил

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал так
в .h файле

```
QWizard createwizard;
```

в .cpp файле

```
createwizard.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
createwizard.setPage(CREATE_PAGE, new WizardCreate);
createwizard.setPage(DISTANCE_PAGE, new WizardDistance);
createwizard.setPage(GROUP_PAGE, new WizardGroup);
createwizard.setPage(PERSON_PAGE, new WizardPerson);
createwizard.show();
```

где `CREATE_PAGE,...` - это перечисление